# Calculating the Jordan form of a easy matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi guys I am trying to practice Jordan form of a matrix ie write $A= P^{-1}JP$ where J is a Jordan block matrix.

\begin{align*}
A &=\begin{bmatrix}
   0       & 1 & 0 & \\
   0       & 0 & 1 \\
   0      & 0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Clearly we see that $\lambda =0$ such that the algebraic multiplicity is 3.

Then I started to calculate the  Eigenvectors and the generalized Eigenvectors.

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   0       & 1 & 0 & \\
   0       & 0 & 1 \\
   0      & 0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus I obtained that $v^T=[1,0,0]$
Then I continued with the generalized Eigen-vectors,

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   0       & 1 & 0 & \\
   0       & 0 & 1 \\
   0      & 0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus we get that $y=1,z=0$ and $x$ can be anything so I am not sure should we say that the generalized Eigen vector is $v_2=[1,1,0]$ or something else. Furthermore I am confused because if $\lambda=0$ we must have our $J$ matrix to be all zeros. Can someone clarify this for me please.

Comment: I think $A$ is already in Jordan form. Except for the upper diagonal consisting of $1$s, the diagonal has got zeros and the rest of the elements are zeros.

Comment: Your second eigenvector is a solution  to $A^2v=0$.